# Despite funding: The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Reason provided by the contract

Tags: remix, solidity-0.8.x

I have the contract below and it even fails with $10 sent in Gas.
[TX link](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x075d2e9e748973a39731b94c5d0aabdb3758bfc4bf037a0fe680546acd88ac09)
Clicking the swap button in Remix on Sepolia chain, the console shows.

```
[vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: Asset.swap(address,address,address) 0xd91...39138value: 0 weidata: 0x933...5aa6flogs: 0hash: 0x9f6...c91ce
status  false Transaction mined but execution failed
transaction hash    0x9f6adcadb10572ed04f2af6676b4a6bd5c8ad07aaac4453258f579fef93c91ce
from    0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4
to  Asset.swap(address,address,address) 0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138
```

The debugger leads to this line:

```
 require(swapAmount > 0 , "You have to at least deposit something to start a DEX");
```

Can anyone spot what I do wrong with funding the contract?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract ERC20Basic is IERC20 {
    string public constant name = "ERC20Basic";
    string public constant symbol = "ERC";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
    uint256 totalSupply_ = 10 ether;

    constructor() {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
    }

    function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
        return totalSupply_;
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender]-numTokens;
        balances[receiver] = balances[receiver]+numTokens;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address delegate, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address delegate) public override view returns (uint) {
        return allowed[owner][delegate];
    }

    function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[owner]);
        require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);

        balances[owner] = balances[owner]-numTokens;
        allowed[owner][msg.sender] = allowed[owner][msg.sender]+numTokens;
        balances[buyer] = balances[buyer]+numTokens;
        emit Transfer(owner, buyer, numTokens);
        return true;
    }
}

contract Asset {
    event AssetSold(address sender, uint256 amount);
    event AssetBought(address sender, uint256 amount);
    event EtherReceived(address sender, uint amount);
    event LogMessage(string message);
    event LogMessages(string message, string message2);
    IERC20 private token;
    address private owner;

    constructor() {}

    //Enforce security everywhere
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only contract owner can call this function");
        _;
    }

    function swap(address _tokenAddress, address _fromAddress, address _toAddress) public payable{
        //fuel
        emit LogMessage("Begin fuel");
        uint256 swapAmount = address(this).balance;
        emit LogMessage("Fuel...");

        require(swapAmount > 0 , "You have to at least deposit something to start a DEX");
        address tokenAddress = address(uint160(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_tokenAddress)))));
        token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
        //buy
        uint256 dexBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(swapAmount <= dexBalance, "Not enough tokens in the reserve");
        token.transfer(_fromAddress, swapAmount);
        emit AssetBought(_fromAddress, swapAmount);
        //sell
        uint256 approvedAmt = token.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(approvedAmt >= swapAmount, "Check the token allowance");
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), swapAmount);
        payable(_toAddress).transfer(swapAmount);
        emit AssetSold(msg.sender, swapAmount);

        sendProfitToWallet();
    }

    function sendProfitToWallet() private {
        //send profit from swap back to wallet
    }

    // Function to receive Ether
    receive() external payable {
        emit EtherReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function getRemainingGas() public view returns (uint256) {
        return gasleft();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to send the contract some ether.
In your case, swapAmount is the ether balance of the Asset contract, and you require that it is greater than 0. If execution halts at that line, then it means swapAmount, which is also your Asset contract balance, is 0.
Send it some ether.

Comment: I thought I did. The TX link above shows a transaction from Metamask to the address of the deployed contract. Given the success of the transaction I think the contract does not "accept" the Eth.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the Asset contract has enough ether. Or attach a certain amount of ether when calling the swap function.

`address tokenAddress = address(uint160(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_tokenAddress)))));`

What does this line of code do?

Comment: This line adds the address of the token to be swapped.
Like Sifu with address: 0xc0aee478e3658e2610c5f7a4a2e1777ce9e4f2ac